# Should I also parse mandatory arguments with getopt(...)

Tags: python

```
"""
Saves a dir listing in a file
Usage: python listfiles.py -d dir -f filename [flags]
Arguments:
  -d, --dir               dir; ls of which will be saved in a file
  -f, --file              filename (if existing will be overwritten)
Flags:
  -h, --help              show this help 
  -v, --verbose           be verbose
"""         

...

def usage():
  print __doc__

def main(args):
  verbose = False
  srcdir = filename = None
  try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(args,
                               'hvd:f:', ['help', 'verbose', 'dir=', 'file='])
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)
  for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
      usage()
      sys.exit(0)
    if opt in ('-v', '--verbose'):
      verbose = True
    elif opt in ('-d', '--dir'):
      srcdir = arg
    elif opt in ('-f', '--file'):
      filename = arg
  if srcdir and filename:
    fsock = open(filename, 'w')
    write_dirlist_tosock(srcdir, fsock, verbose)
    fsock.close()
  else:
    usage()
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I am not sure if it is pythonic to use `getopt()` to also handle mandatory arguments. Would appreciate some suggestions

Comment: I can recommend [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Also check out plac (even more simpler): http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `getopt` module is only for those users who are already familiar with the same module in C, the python standard argument handling is [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 1):

"Mandatory Options" is a contradiction, and is not generally well supported by the various option parsing libraries;  You should consider placing mandatory arguments as a positional arguments, not parsed by the option parser, this would agree with common practice much better.

Comment: yes! this is exactly my question, I think I will edit the title. Can you please elaborate on "consider placing mandatory arguments as a positional arguments"

Comment: when executing the parser, the usually return a 2-tuple, the first item being the parsed options, and the second is the *rest* of the arguments the parser didn't recognize.  These are called the positional arguments, and it's typical to expect a certain combination of them, in a certain order.